# How to hide / encrypt POST data sent from FLASH to PHP from Tamper Data

Tags: sql, actionscript-3, security, flash, token

**Tamper data**

There is terrible thing called *Tamper Data*. It receives all *POST'ing* data from *FLASH* to *PHP* and give ability for user to change values.

Imagine that in flash game (written in *ActionScript 3*) are score points and time. After match completed score and time variables are sending to *PHP* and inserting to database.

But user can easy change values with *Tamper Data* after match completed. So changed values will be inserted to database.

---

**My idea seems that won't work**

I had idea to update data in database on every change? I mean If player get +10 score points I need instant to write It to database. But how about time? I need update my table in database every milisecond? Is that protection solution at all? If user can change *POST* data he can change It everytime also last time when game completed.

---

**So how to avoid 3rd party software like *Tamper Data*?**

**Tokens.** I've read article about *[Tokens](http://spalatnik.com/blog/?p=23)*, there is talking about how to create random string as token and compare It with database, but It's not detailed and I don't have idea how to realise It. Is that good idea? If yes, maybe someone how to realise It practically?

Answer (score 0):

According to me is better way to send both parameter and value in encrypted format like `score=12` send like `c2NvcmU9MTI=` which is *base64*

```
function encrypt($str)
{
     $s = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5(SALTKEY), serialize($str), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5(SALTKEY)))), '+/=', '-_,');
 return $s;

}

function decrypt($str)
{
    $s = unserialize(rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5(SALTKEY), base64_decode(strtr($str, '-_,', '+/=')), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5(SALTKEY))), "\0"));
 return $s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, seems like good solution. I will test It a bit later and will inform you if that worked for me.

Comment: yes...but make sure your encryption and decryption must be unbreakable by attacker

Comment: What do you mean must be unbreakable by attacker?

Comment: see GOOGLE OWASP for more details

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no way to protect the content generated in Flash and sent to server.

Even if you encrypt the data with a secret key, both the key and the encryption algorithm are contained in the swf file and can be decompiled. It is a bit more harder than simply faking the data so it is kind of usable solution but it will not always help.

To have full security, you need to run all game simulation on the server. For example, if player jumped and catched a coin, Flash does not send "score +10" to the server. Instead, it sends player coordinates and speed, and server does the check: where is the coin, where is the player, what is player's speed and can the player get the coin or not.

If you cannot run the full simulation on the server, you can do a partial check by sending data to server at some intervals.

First, never send a "final" score or any other score. It is very easy to fake. Instead, send an event every time the player does something that changes his score.

For example, every time player catches a coin, you send this event to the server. You may not track player coordinates or coin coordinates, but you know that the level contains only 10 coins. So player cannot catch more than 10 coins anyway. Also, player can't catch coins too fast because you know the minimum distance between coins and the maximum player speed.

You should not write the data to database each time you receive it. Instead you need to keep each player's data in memory and change it there. You can use a noSQL database for that, for example Redis.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, but I think here will be problems with It. I'm using simple MySQL database and game's score points depending on time. Here is total 30 seconds (countdown timer) and points are adding depending on time, if left 29 seconds for dragged and dropped item to correct place player receive 29 points, if left 12 seconds = 12 points and etc. So I don't know if that is possible to achive It.

Comment: And just to re-enforce how difficult and not completely solvable of a problem cheating is: even if you move 100% of the game logic to the server, and the client is only an input for command requests to the server, a hacker could write a bot that plays the game perfectly.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas if it is drag and drop game, you can do the following: count only drop events. When player drops the item, first check it on client, if it does not achieve score then don't send to server; otherwise call the server and pass all the needed data. On server, add score accordingly (you can also check the remaining time there) and update the database. A player cannot drag and drop succesfully several times per second, so having one update per player per 1-2 seconds is ok.

Comment: Additionally, you can encrypt the data with a dynamic key that you receive from server. After each call to the server it will return a new key (based on the server's secret hidden key) for next request. So if someone is doing a hack, it would be difficult to change the data on the fly with a third-party software.

Answer (score 0):

First, cheaters will always cheat. There's really no easy solution (or difficult one) to completely prevent it. There are lots of articles on the great lengths developers have gone to discourage cheating, yet it is still rampant in nearly every game with any popularity.

That said, here are a few suggestions to hopefully discourage cheating:

1. Encrypt your data. This is not unbeatable, but will discourage many lazy hackers since they can't just tamper with plain http traffic, they first have to find your encryption keys. Check out [as3corelib for AS3 encryption](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/tree/master/src/com/adobe/crypto).
2. Obfuscate your SWFs. [There are a few tools out there to do this for you.](http://coldconstructs.com/2010/07/swf-protection/) Again, this isn't unbeatable, but it is an easy way to make it harder for cheaters to find your encryption keys.
3. Move all your timing logic to the server. Instead of your client telling the server about time, tell the server about actions like "GAME_STARTED" and "SCORED_POINTS". The server then tracks the user's time and calculates the final score. The important thing here is that the client **does not** tell the server anything related to time, but merely the action taken and the server uses its own time.
4. If you can establish any rules about maximum possible performance (for example 10 points per second) you can detect some types of cheating on the server. For example, if you receive SCORED_POINTS=100 but the maximum is 10, you have a cheater. Or, if you receive SCORED_POINTS=10, then SCORE_POINTS=10 a few milliseconds later, and again a few milliseconds later, you probably have a cheater. Be careful with this, and know that it's a back and forth battle. Cheaters will always come up with clever ways to get around your detection logic, and you don't want your detection logic to be so strict that you accidentally reject an honest player (perhaps a really skilled player who is out-performing what you initially thought possible).
5. When you detect a cheater, ["honey pot"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_%28computing%29) them. Don't tell them they are cheating, as this will only encourage them to find ways to avoid detection.